# Unity button with attached script cannot detect function after adding "ref"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, boolean, ref

After attaching it to unity UI button, the function cannot be found under `click()`. However, if i were to remove the `ref`, i can see it. How can i solve this?

```
public bool bool1 = false;
public bool bool2 = false;
public bool bool3 = false;
....
public bool bool100 = false;

public void ChangeBool(ref bool a)
{
    a = true;
}
```

My goal is to create a single function for many buttons which will change each individual boolean each.

I understand that i can create 100 functions for 100 booleans but my worries is that the script will get very long.

Comment: Why have so many bool sin the first place? Sounds like you rather want some sort of array/dictionary instead and then you could just have a method with both parameters, an index/key + value

Answer (score 0):

In inspector you can't add a method with parameter

```
btn.onClick.AddListener(() => { Function(param); OtherFunction(param); })
```

With lambda expression you can add that method in code btn is button for sure.

Comment: `In inspector you can't add a method with parameter` -> you can, but not with a `ref` parameter and not dynamic .. sounds to me like OP is rather trying to overwrite a certain field with a certain pre-configured value from the Inspector